# Logic Check on Adding subview to a view - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, subview

Will it work if I create two different view controllers using storyboard (VC1 and VC2) and then add VC2 to VC1 as a subview programmatically? This VC2 has buttons to be accessed which is managed using a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

use protocol to define a delegate method in VC1 controller...

Comment: http://www.infosegment.com/?p=244

Here anotherViewController is VC2 and someViewController is VC1...

Comment: is it possible to maintain the transparency of the VC2?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a UIViewController view as a subview/modal on top of another UIViewController view, such as that the subview/modal should be transparent and you need to setup the delegate for passing value between two views. You may see this example of how to add UIViewController view on the top of another UIViewController view: [Display clearColor UIViewController over UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236367/display-clearcolor-uiviewcontroller-over-uiviewcontroller)