# Display clear colored ViewController over another ViewController in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, transparency

Prior to iOS 7, according to this popular Stackoverflow [question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236367/display-clearcolor-uiviewcontroller-over-uiviewcontroller) the way to show a ViewController with a clear background was to do the following in the main ViewController:

```
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

However, as I have recently discovered with iOS 7 (and as commented by others to the main answer), the above solution no longer works, and instead just shows a black model controller.  I know that transparency is largely used in iOS 7, so that transparent view controller is very likely possible.  I haven't discovered a workaround to this issue yet, and was wondering if anyone knows how to resolve this problem.  Thanks!

Comment: `modalPresentationStyle` documentation now states: "On iPhone and iPod touch, modal view controllers are always presented full-screen, but on iPad there are several different presentation options". So I assume Apple took this away for iPhone in iOS 7.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/q/27598846/1603234 make me smile, now your turn :)

Comment: Swift Verion http://stackoverflow.com/a/34578402/3380878

Answer (score 8):

I just followed the original solution and applied some default and custom settings in Interface Builder, and seems to me it is working.

- You can check it here: https://github.com/codedad/SO_IOS_viewcl_on_viewcl

Important section (quite similar to the question's code):

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"click");


    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TopOverVc"];

    vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

- Also pls find the IB snaphot:
  [image]
- And the simulator result (after pressing button):

[image]

Hope I did not misunderstand sthing in your question ;) Happy coding!

Comment: had a similar problem, I checked your code and works ;) thx for @daspianist for the question too!

Comment: Does not work if the main view controller is embedded within a navigation controller.

Comment: i'm getting the black background do u know y?? @codedad

Comment: works only on ipad not in iphone :P

Comment: Not working , it showing black background.

Comment: This does not work with iOS 9 anymore.

Answer (score -2):

For iOS 7,subclass SecondViewController and try setting the view background color in viewDidLoad of SecondViewController

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score -3):

Why not u r using this

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];

    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:nil];

 vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Try to change BG Color of View after view is loaded.
in ur sol u r first changing View and the presenting. the View Life cycle not going on this manner

Comment: Thanks for the solution - however this didn't work either..  I am still getting the all black background upon calling the VC.

Comment: getting Black background