# Present a modal view controller with transparent background

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I want to present a `UIViewController` programmatically which should show up (or not, rather) with transparent background. I want it for iOS 7.0 and above. I've find myself many questions (and answers) but they weren't able to help me. Here's the view hierarchy of my app.

I'm using a side menu controller (RESideMenu).

I have a rootView (base from RESideMenu) -> Showing a Center controller (along with a left view controller) in `UINavigationController`.

In requirements, I'd like to present a view controller

> From a pushed view controller (in navigational hierarchy)
>
> From a presented view controller (in navigational hierarchy)

In addition, I need to present it and perform some action, and then remove it.

I'm pretty sure that this should work in many cases, with (or without) side menu, or even navigation controller.

I'm posting a separate question (and of course its answer too) into this queue, because I think it would prove helpful to the community devs who might also have been frustrated by the lack of an acceptable solution to this problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Suppose, we're in `FirstViewController`

```
//Obj-C
- (void) presentSecondVC {
    SecondViewController *vc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [self didMoveToParentViewController:vc];
}

//Swift
func presentSecondVC() {
    let vc = SecondViewController.init()
    self.addChildViewController(vc)
    self.didMove(toParentViewController: vc)
}
```

> Some of you may need to write above method like this,

```
//Obj-C
- (void) presentSecondVC {
    SecondViewController *vc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,width,height); //Your own CGRect
    [self.view addSubview:vc.view]; //If you don't want to show inside a specific view
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [self didMoveToParentViewController:vc];
    //for someone, may need to do this.
    //[self.navigationController addChildViewController:vc];
    //[self.navigationController didMoveToParentViewController:vc];   
}

//Swift
func presentSecondVC() {
    let vc = SecondViewController.init()
    vc.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height) //Your own CGRect
    self.view.addSubview(vc.view) //If you don't want to show inside a specific view.
    self.addChildViewController(vc)
    self.didMove(toParentViewController: vc)
    //for someone, may need to do this.
    //self.navigationController?.addChildViewController(vc)
    //self.navigationController?.didMove(toParentViewController: vc)
}
```

> Now in `SecondViewController` when you want to go back

```
//Obj-C
- (void) goBack {
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
}

//Swift
func goBack() {
    self.removeFromParentViewController()
}
```

Do play well (with each scenario) :)

And yes, this will not show an animation, in my case, I'm showing a custom popup inside `vc` though it looks nice with this code!

Comment: To, **Dear Downvoters**, please try consider to keep your footprint here with a comment about the reason of your down vote. It would be really helpful to learn something and improve my self. I keep my answer here (as in my question) to help you (and other devs, may be). However if it looks bad or not worked for you then feel free to write your word (and if possible your solution too) along with your disagreed down vote. I'll surely appreciated it, thanks! :)

Comment: The method `goBack` is incomplete, `removeFromSuperView` should be called. `UIViewController Class Reference` is for you.

Comment: You need to add [self.view addSubview:vc.view]; this line in both cases .... only addChildViewController will do nothing ...

Comment: The main reason for the downvotes is your answer say how to add child view controller and not how to present a view controller there is a big difference between them. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH14-SW1 for whoever is interested read apples docs

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh, thanks for stopping by, this question has been asked and answered by me a few years back. Please feel free to edit question details or my answer to have the perfect picture. And yes, ATB for the Doovery! :) P.S. I no longer mind for the downvoters.