# Presenting a modal ViewController which has semi transparent background

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm presenting a `SecondViewController` modally on `FirstViewController` and the `SecondViewController` has a semi transparent background (White color with 70 percent opacity).

The problem I'm facing is when I present `SecondViewController`, the view of `FirstViewController` remains visible until the `SecondViewController` has finished presenting.

This makes the UI look laggy. The behaviour I'm expecting is as soon as the `SecondViewController` is presented, the view for `FirstViewController` should be invisible, or gradually faded out before the view of `SecondViewController` appears.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

The code I use for presenting is :

```
SecondViewController *cntrlr = (SecondViewController *)[[UIStoryboard activationStoryboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“UserVC”];
[cntrlr setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
[self presentViewController:cntrlr animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: can you put some code of model present?

Comment: @yagneshdobariya I've edited the question, plz have a look

Comment: pls have a look on answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SecondViewController *cntrlr = (SecondViewController *)[[UIStoryboard activationStoryboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@“UserVC”];
[cntrlr setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
self.view.alpha = 0.0f;  
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
[self presentViewController:cntrlr animated:YES completion:nil];
```

`// Need to set FirstViewController alpha 1.0f after dismisViewControlle`r

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.view.alpha = 1.0f;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: is this answer helpful to u?

Answer (score 0):

After iOS 3.2 there is a method to do this without any “tricks” – see the documentation for the modalPresentationStyle property. You have a rootViewController which will present the viewController. So here's the code to success:

```
viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[rootViewController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

With this method the viewController's background will be transparent and the underlying rootViewController will be visible.

Comment: What i want is the underlying rootViewController should not visible. It should disappear as soon as I modally present the viewcontroller.. Currently, the underlying controller is visible for some duration at the back of the presented viewcontroller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598846/present-a-modal-view-controller-with-transparent-background check this @Hemang do the trick you will set the view alpha:0.7 you will get the semi transparent