# How to partially Present a viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have custom tableview (xib) in freeform size with height 350pts.
I want to present that tableview partially as shown in the picture, but when I try to `presentViewController` with that 350 height still, it appears to present in the whole screen not as I desired.

****IMAGE*****

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3Q2nuVLZgySY2laVWtKRDQtdVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: create a transparent background on your present viewcontroller and add all other view to subview to transparent view simple

Comment: will that do in storyboard?

Comment: you can implement this concept in any userinterface

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19486530/display-clear-colored-viewcontroller-over-another-viewcontroller-in-ios-7

Comment: again I wanted a navigation bar on top of the tableview as in picture, how do i do that in this case?

Comment: ok I add this fucntion when you need this view means if you press the button or else

Comment: yes when i press a button then a partial present modal viewcontroller should appears

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik basically what i want is to have some view on top of the tableview just to show the name that's it.

Comment: set the frame to window not for view , you can get the same output for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [`UIPresentationController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPresentationController_class/index.html), this is exactly what you want.

It's very complicated because you have to implement a lot of things, but you will be able to constraint in code the viewport of your view controller, make animations alongside the system ones and update layout for any sizeclass.

---

Or, you can make your child view controller with a transparent top margin background.

Comment: can do this using storyboard

Answer (score 0):

In apple documentation.

> The size and position of the root view is determined by the object
>   that owns it, which is either a parent view controller or the app’s
>   window. The view controller that is owned by the window is the app’s
>   root view controller and its view is sized to fill the window.

Comment: Note: the viewcontroller which i want  to be shown partially is not an root view controller

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the y coordinate of your table view and set its height to the height of your super view minus y.
For ex:-tableView.frame=CGRectMake(x,100,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-100);

Hope this work.