# When animating a viewController on top, the one in the back disappears.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have a `viewController` which displays a map with annotations. When I click on a bar button, another `viewController` is supposed to animate on top of that. This works, BUT, when the animation completes, the `viewController` in the back disappears. It reappears again when the animated `viewController` closes again.

Here is a [video](http://videobam.com/DQTSG) of what happens - hopefully that will make things more clear:

Let me know if I should include the code as well.

Comment: I saw your video. But, it is not helpful. Can you please add your code?

Comment: Check this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236367/display-clearcolor-uiviewcontroller-over-uiviewcontroller/11252969#11252969**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you present a view controller it is expected to take the full screen. As such, the view controllers 'below' it have their views removed from the stack to save resources which are expected to not be required.

You can change your presented view controller to do something like:

1. Either, don't be presented, just add a subview and animate it in.
2. Or, pass an image of the original view to the presented view, this becomes the background and that presented view animates a subview in over the image background.

Comment: Note: As mentioned in the link in the comment by Kumar KI, in iOS7 if you set the `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationCustom` your background viewController will remain.

Comment: I debugged my code a litta bit - in my completion block i write: [transitionContext completeTransition:YES]. If i just set that ti nil - the transition "freezes" BUT the view in the back does not go away.

Comment: The transition completion is the trigger to remove non-required resources because that is when the source view is no longer visible.