# Show transparent background for modal view

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, uinavigationcontroller

I want to show a modal view via my navigation controller, and background of this view should be transparent. In the modal view controller I clear background on viewDidLoad as follow:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

I show this view as follow:

```
ModalViewController *modalViewController = [[ModalViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:modalViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

As result my view is shown, but background is black. I've tried to do:

```
[self setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
```

For all my view controllers, include NavigationController. I've tried to do:

```
self.navigationController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
self.navigationController.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

However all of this doesn't work. Is it possible to implement my task, or I should show my view using another way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this question on SO [Display clearColor UIViewController over UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236367/display-clearcolor-uiviewcontroller-over-uiviewcontroller)?

It seems to have the answer to your question. Basically you have to set
presentation style to 'UIModalPresentationCurrentContext'.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I wrote your link carefully and have found my issue there :)

Answer (score 0):

I used UIModalPresentationCurrentContext instead of the UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext. Using the UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext fixed this issue.