# Rewinding from VC2 presented Over Current Context not reloading original VC1

Tags: ios

I have a PresentingViewController (VC1) and a PresentedViewController (VC2).

VC1 --Segue:Present Modally:Over Current Context-->  VC2

VC2 --RewindSegue --> VC1

The problem is that when I rewind from VC2 to VC1, it is not being "reloaded".  It is nil.
However if I present VC 2 modally: Full Screen, the rewind triggers a reload of VC1 and all is dandy.

Why does a rewind FROM a VC presented "Modally:Over Current Context" not reload the VC you are rewinding to?  How can I present over Current Context and also force a reload of VC1 when I rewind?

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding the function I wanted to update in VC1 in the unwinding action

```
@IBAction func unwindToDetailViewControllerVC1(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    println("Unwinding to DetailViewControllerVC1")
    rememberWhatSegmentIsPressed()

}
```

Also remember to tick the 'Defines Context' in the presentingViewController.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27487057/4051036