# "Over Current Context" option not available in Xcode Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

In this answer on Stack Overflow, [Display clearColor UIViewController over UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236367/display-clearcolor-uiviewcontroller-over-uiviewcontroller/28355354#28355354), the user suggests using the `Over Current Context` option for a modal view controller.

The goal is to create a transparent modal view controller, all through Storyboard.

But the `Over Current Context` option isn't available. Only `Current Context,` which doesn't create a transparent modal controller.

Answer (score 2):

Been wrestling with this same issue for some time, and finally found a workaround.

Using Xcode 7.2.

Not sure exactly why this is happening, but `Over Current Context` is not an available option. This project was created some time ago, which I have a hunch could be related.

[image: current context]

As a test, I created a brand new project, and `Over Current Context` is an option.

[image: over current context]

Since deleting and recreating my existing project was out of the question, I ended up doing the following:

1. Set the `Presentation` on the segue to `Default`. This is preparation for the next step.
2. On the destination view controller scene, set `Presentation` to `Over Current Context` within the `Attributes Inspector`.

[image: destination view controller]

I was able to successfully see the parent view controller underneath the semi-transparent modal.

**Note:**

I'm supporting iOS 8 and above, so I don't have to mess around with setting the `modalPresentationStyle` on the parent vs. the child.

**Failed attempts:**

- Setting `modalPresentationStyle` to `.OverCurrentContext` on the destination view controller in `prepareForSegue` did not work for me, because the Storyboard setting seemed to override my code.
- Setting `Defines Context` and `Provides Context` did not seem to make a difference. I'm guessing these could come into play for some app architectures, just not my in my particular project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you supporting iOS 7? Over Current Context is iOS 8 only.

Answer (score 0):

`IOS 7` can totally handle `Over Current context`, just be sure to check `use size classes` on the `File inspector`.

[image: Example here:]