# Custom UIViewControllerContextTransitioning and black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I have a UITableViewController, inside my UITableViewCell i have an imageView when the user taps on it, i present it modally using my own custom UIViewControllerContextTransitioning to make a zoom effect on it, it works like a charm the problem is that when the animation completes and i call the

```
[transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
```

My UITableView which is now behind my Modal UIViewController is removed form the view hierarchy so i got a black screen behind it

```
 [containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];
 [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:damping initialSpringVelocity:1.0 / damping options:0 animations:^{
    // blablabla animation stuff
 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
   [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];// this line makes my UITableView removed form the view hierarchy 
 }];
```

Here is what i've tried so far :

add in the completion bloc the UITableView

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication ].keyWindow insertSubview:fromViewController.view belowSubview:containerView];
```

But this only works on iOS8 ...

Any ideas how to fix this ? thank you !!

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31940627/765298

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `modalPresentationStyle` of the presenting view controller to `UIModalPresentationCustom`

Comment: it is set to UIModalPresentationCustom i tried others values and it didn't work too