# iOS: how to push ViewController over current context?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have VC and I want to push it and to see the VC that under it.

I can do it if I present if modally ([Display clearColor UIViewController over UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236367/display-clearcolor-uiviewcontroller-over-uiviewcontroller))

But is it possible to implement this feature via push VC? Or I need to create custom transition ?

Comment: Take an image of the view and make it the background of the next view

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Wain's comment:

- you can render the parent view in a `UIImage`;
- you then set this image as the background of your new view.

Here is a possible implementation in Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // render parent view in a UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    self.parent?.view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // add the image as background of the view
    self.view.insertSubview(UIImageView(image: viewImage), at: 0)
```