# Presenting transparent view controller over another

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to present a view controller over another one, where the upper will be transparent , and the bottom would have this blur effect.

What happened is that i see a black background in the presented view, although its clear colour.

I have also read here, and did exactly the same :
[Display clearColor UIViewController over UIViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236367/display-clearcolor-uiviewcontroller-over-uiviewcontroller)

```
//to present     
PillView *pillv=[[PillView alloc]initWithPill:pill WithNum:num];
     pillv.delegate=self;


    UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
    blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];

    UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
    visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    visualEffectView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, [Globals sharedGlobals].titleHeight*self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:visualEffectView];



    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:pillv animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: are ou testing it with the simulator or the device?

Comment: simulator , is there a problem with it ?

Comment: checked also in device not working..

Comment: so you want to make pillView transparent ?

Comment: yes. it is transparent actually, i set its background to clear

Comment: even though you set its background to color, there will be a window behind the view of every view controller, and it is black always!!

Comment: have you read my question? this is the exact link i posted here and i do the same.

Comment: Have you read the complete answer?

Comment: What I am thinking is, When you present a view controller, the previous view controller will no longer in the view heirarchy, and there will be a window which is black in color, will be show to you, if you set the view to clear color.

Comment: you need to make it a xib,so that you can add it as subview (which will be shown on top of blur view )

Comment: you mean to make it a UIView ? well , i cant do that because its already a huge code and changing that is a problem.

Comment: I know, thing you see in black color is actually a window. You loose all the old view hierarchy when you present a new one.  A window cannot store references of two uiview controllers at the same time. It can only store the references of UIviews.

Comment: you may find useful info here http://theiconmaster.com/2015/03/transitioning-between-view-controllers-in-the-same-window-with-swift-mac/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `UIVisualEffectView` to the presented View Controller, and not the one that is doing the presentation.

```
PillView *pillv=[[PillView alloc]initWithPill:pill WithNum:num];
     pillv.delegate=self;


UIVisualEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];

UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
visualEffectView.frame= pillv.view.bounds;
pillv.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[pillv.view insertSubview:visualEffectView atIndex:0];

self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:pillv animated:NO completion:nil];
```

And because the OP seems to be thinking my solution is not working, here is a sample project to show this:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29456419/blurTest.zip

And here are the pictures of the view (presenting) and then the OverlayView:

[image: Presenting ViewController][image: Overlay ViewController]

Comment: i dont think this is what i am looking for. i would like the bottom view controller to be blurred, where there is the pillV above it.

Comment: isnt this create a blur effect on presented view? I think OP asked for transparent view!!!

Comment: and it still not solving the problem of transparent view controller. because i will not see the bottom view anyway in your method.

Comment: When you add a `UIVisualEffectView` on a clear UIViewController, the parent (presenting) viewController view is shown as blured. This is what he wants

Comment: @Curnelious Have you tried what I am showing you? Because I am using this on my application and it works. The only difference is that I am setting the presented View controller properties on the `viewDidLoad` delegate of that view controller, but I don't think it makes a difference

Comment: Hmm, and that does this `[pillv.view addSubview:visualEffectView];` do then ?

Comment: you add the visual to pillv, and then pillv to self ? well not only that its very strange thing to do, it still shows black screen ...

Comment: are you serious ?? this is a very wrong thing to do . you create some view controller, then you add above it a blur (? you cover it with a blur?) and then you add both of them to self ?? this is completely different from what i wants. I would like to have a bottom view(self) and above it, present a new view controller, where this one(above) is transparent and you see the bottom view (self) in a blur mode .

Comment: It's not strange. It's how it should be done. You are showing a ViewController (pillv) over the existing one. The one you are showing needs to be transparent (pillV background) and then you add the visualEffectView in the pillV as the background. Try my edited solution as the visualEffectView needs to be at the bottom of the view hierarchy and change the presentationStyle to `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`

Comment: tried that. still a black screen because of that same problem that you cant make a view to be transparent ...

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing, but here is a sample project so you can see that it does work: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29456419/blurTest.zip

Comment: @Curnelious Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: yes it didn't worked but i will accept your answer because you tried .

Comment: it works, but `self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;` should be `pillv.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;`

Answer (score 3):

From Ios 8 and upper please use UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext instead of UIModalPresentationCurrentContext

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext` for the presentation style if on iOS8 or higher.

However, the key setting is that you need to set `definesPresentationContext` to true for the presenting controller you wish to be seen showing through.

From the documentation:

> UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext
>
> A presentation style where the content is displayed over a view
>   controller’s content whose definesPresentationContext property is YES.
>   UIKit may walk up the view controller hierarchy to find a view
>   controller that wants to define the presentation context. The views
>   beneath the presented content are not removed from the view hierarchy
>   when the presentation finishes. So if the presented view controller
>   does not fill the screen with opaque content, the underlying content
>   shows through.
>
> When presenting a view controller in a popover, this presentation
>   style is supported only if the transition style is
>   UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical. Attempting to use a different
>   transition style triggers an exception. However, you may use other
>   transition styles (except the partial curl transition) if the parent
>   view controller is not in a popover.
>
> Available in iOS 8.0 and later.

So:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:pillv animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: May be `pillv.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;`?

Comment: @Cy-4AH I think it has to be set on the controller which defines the context for modal presentation, hence `self`.