# Is there a way to show a modal popover with specific reduced view?

Tags: ios, swift, uipopover

I open a popover by segue and cover the whole current view controller. I would like to cover just the dimensions (width and height) of this popover because it is lesser than current view controller.

Comment: You can popover view controller with clear background colour and put UIView to your "clear ViewController" . this question should help you to create viewController with clear background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236367/display-clearcolor-uiviewcontroller-over-uiviewcontroller

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I would like with the current background. Moreover I'm using swift and this link is for object c.

Comment: You can find there option for swift (You can also set it up in UI). And you can put the background to your custom UIView which will represent your "viewController" . Unfortunately I do not know about other solution :/